# How to register multiple implementations with its own interface in ASP.NET Core using Reflection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, dependency-injection

I'm new to the Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core 3.1, and I'm trying to create Singleton instances of my Repository classes using Reflection, but I can't get it to work.

Currently, the `BookService` uses the `BookRepository` from the DI:

```cs
public class BookService : IBookService
{
    private readonly IBookRepository _bookRepository;

    public BookService(IBookRepository bookRepository)
    {
        _bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public async Task<Book> GetById(string id)
    {
        var find = await _bookRepository.FindAsync(id);
        return find;
    }
}
```

It works because I added a singleton service to the container, with the following code ([link to Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions_AddSingleton__2_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_)):
`services.AddSingleton<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();`

I'm trying to achieve the same result using Reflection.

`BookRepository`

```cs
public class BookRepository : BaseRepository<Book>, IBookRepository
{
}
```

`IBookRepository`

```cs
public interface IBookRepository : IAsyncRepository<Book>
{
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
// Get all classes implementing IAsyncRepository
var repositoryTypes = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(x => !x.IsInterface
        && x.GetInterface(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>).Name) != null);
        
foreach (var repositoryType in repositoryTypes)
{
   // Adds a singleton service of BookRepository
   services.AddSingleton(repositoryType);
}
```

But as you can see, the code above is adding only the `BookRepository`, missing to reference the `IBookRepository` interface, so it's throwing the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'IBookRepository' for service type 'IBookRepository'.'

````
Do you know how can I do that?

**EDIT:** This is the implementation I made to solve the problem:

``` c#
public static class DependencyInjectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddApplicationServices(
        this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        RegisterImplementationsOfServiceType(
            services, assembly, typeof(IService));
        RegisterImplementationsOfServiceType(
            services, assembly, typeof(IAsyncRepository<>));
    }

    private static void RegisterImplementationsOfServiceType(
        IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly, Type type)
    {
        var implementationsType = assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(x => !x.IsInterface && x.GetInterface(type.Name) != null);
            
        foreach (var implementationType in implementationsType)
        {
            var servicesType = implementationType.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(r => !r.Name.Contains(type.Name));
                
            foreach (var serviceType in servicesType)
            {
                services.AddSingleton(serviceType, implementationType);
            }
        }
    }
}
````

Comment: IMHO, define an attribute `ServiceInterfaceAttribute`, add it to `IBookRepository`, scan the assembly for any type implementing an interface with the attribute? That might simplify your dynamic configuration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
// Get all classes implementing IAsyncRepository
var repositoryTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => !x.IsInterface &&  
x.GetInterface(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>).Name) != null);
foreach (var repositoryType in repositoryTypes)
{
    var type = repositoryType.UnderlyingSystemType;
    services.AddSingleton(type.GetInterface($"I{type.Name}"), type);
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to get the interface type

Comment: this may work for the specific case of the OP and as long as the naming convention is followed ( I mean about `IService` for interface and `Service` for implementation) :) Generally it may fail. You can just get all the interfaces of the filtered types (using `GetInterfaces`) and register each pair of each interface & the type. That would cover all the pairs of interface & class and has a better result.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It worked! Hey @KingKing you meant like this? 
```var interfacesType = repositoryType.GetInterfaces().Where(r => !r.Name.Contains(typeof(IAsyncRepository<>).Name));
``` so I can just loop the all interfaces of the class and add the singleton to the service: `services.AddSingleton(interfaceType, repositoryType);` what do you think?

Comment: @Gabriel that would try registering the services of `IAsyncRepository` so it will miss the interface like `IBookRepository`, actually you need a convention or rule to select the interfaces you want, as in your case I understand that `IBookRepository` is what need to be registered (not `IAsyncRepository`). If you don't have specific convention or rule to filter for the interfaces (from `GetInterfaces()`), then you can just register all with the implementation, it's no harm (with a little bit of extra memory consumed by the DI container).